# Can $K[x,y,z]$ be isomorphic to $K[t]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have a problem which I can't understand. I have two polynomial rings:  $K[x,y,z]$ and $K[t]$ over the field $K$. In the first part the problem asks if $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism:

$$ \phi : K[x,y,z] \longrightarrow K[t]$$
defined by: $$ \phi (x) =t \\ \phi(y)=t^2 \\ \phi(z)= t^3$$

And in the second part it asks to describe  $\ker \phi $.

I showed that $ \phi $ is a homomorphism by showing that:
$ \ \ \phi (1_{K[x,y,z]})= 1_{K[t]} \ \ \ ; \ \ \phi(f+g)=\phi(f)+\phi(g) \ \ ; \ \ \phi(kf)=k\phi(f).\ $
The homomorphism is also  surjective because: $ \forall g \in K[t] \ ,\ g= \sum{a_it^i} \ ,\ \exists \ f \in K[x,y,z] \ ,\ f=\sum{a_ix^i} \ , \text{ s.t. } \phi(f)=\phi(\sum{a_ix^i})= \sum {a_i \phi(x^i)} = \sum{a_it^i=g} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $
But I have a problem in the second part. I described the  $\ker \phi $ as:
$\ker \phi = \{ f \in K[x,y,z] \mid \phi(f)= 0_{K[t]} \} = \{f = \sum {a_{ijk}x^iy^jz^k}  \in K[x,y,z]\mid \phi(f) = \sum{a_{ijk}t^{i+2j+3k}}=0 \} $.

I thought that the only way $\sum{a_{ijk}t^{i+2j+3k}}=0$ is that all the coefficients are $0 $ but in this way the original polynomial is $f=0$. So this means that the map is bijective and so that $ K[x,y,z] \simeq K[t] $. Is that possible? Because it seems odd to me.

Comment: To prove that $\phi$ is a *ring* homomorphism you must also show that $\phi(fg)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$.

Comment: The map is obviously not bijective.  what is $\phi(x^2-y)$, say?

Comment: With no relations on the indeterminates, the answer is no K[x,y,z] cannot be isomorphic to K[t]. In fact there cannot be an injection of K[x,y,z] into K[t] as this would imply a surjection of an affine line onto affine 3-space.

Comment: Note that when $\phi$ is given as simply "defined by $\phi(x)=\ldots, \phi(y)=\ldots,\phi(z)=\ldots$" (and tacitly, also the identity on $K$), then showing the homomorphism property is moot. The very definition of $\phi$ uses the universal property of polynomial rings that they can be and are uniquely dfeined by a homomorphism of the base ring and specifying images for the indeterminates.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: no, because one ring is a PID but the other isn’t.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $$\ker\phi=(xy-z,x^2-y).$$

It is obvious that $xy-z,x^2-y\in\ker\phi$.

For the converse, let $f\in\ker\phi$. That is, $f(t,t^2,t^3)=0$.

Now write $$f(x,y,z)=(xy-z)g(x,y,z)+r(x,y).$$ Then write $$r(x,y)=(x^2-y)s(x,y)+a(x).$$ Since $f(t,t^2,t^3)=0$ we get $a(t)=0$ which implies $f\in(xy-z,x^2-y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum{a_{ijk}t^{i+2j+3k}}=0$ means that for each $n$ we have $S_n = \sum_{(i,j,k) \in A_n} a_{ijk} = 0$, where $A_n  = \{(i,j,k) \mid i +2j +3k = n\}$. In particular we get
$$a_{000} = 0  \\ a_{100} = 0 \\ a_{200} + a_{010} = 0 \\ a_{300} + a_{110} + a_{001} = 0 \\ \ldots$$